# auth0 - invalid user_metadata type

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I am using Auth0 for user management and I am trying to add some default user_metadata on signup. My signup code looks like this:

```
// signs a user up
signup(email, password, callback, metadata){
    const defaultVals = {
        app_complete: false,
        app_decision: 'unknown',
        app_term: this.getAppTerm(),
        nickname: '',
        middle_initial: '',
        current_age: '10',
    }

    const meta = Object.assign({}, defaultVals, metadata);

    console.log(meta);

this.auth0.redirect.signupAndLogin({
  connection: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
  email,
  password,
        user_metadata: meta,
}, function(err, authResult) {
  if (err != undefined) {
    callback(err);
            console.log(err);
            return;
  }
});}
```

The problem is, whenever I try to pass the user_metadata attribute `app_complete: false`, the API returns an error saying that the data type `false` is invalid, and that only strings are allowed. Error message: invalid user_metadata.app_complete type (only strings are allowed).

I know JSON allows for types other than strings, because I can change this to `false` through the Auth0 user dashboard. Why is the signup method for the `auth0` WebAuth object returning this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because for signup in the `user_metadata` you can provide only strings as values.

```
The user metadata to be associated with the user. If set, the field must be an object containing no more than ten properties. Property names can have a maximum of 100 characters, and property values must be strings of no more than 500 characters.
```

PATCH on the other hand supports full JSON types in `user_metadata`.

Here is the reference in the [github auth0-js issue](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/issues/843)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the **user_metadata** in the **signupAndLogin**() ([/dbconnections/signup](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#signup) endpoint) method. However, it has some restriction as described below.

> The user metadata to be associated with the user. If set, the field
>   must be an object containing no more than ten properties. Property
>   names can have a maximum of 100 characters, and property values must
>   be strings of no more than 500 characters.

**To solve the issue, pass the property value as string.**

Alternatively, instead of passing the **user_metadata** in the request, It is possible to use auth0 rules and update the **user_metadata** on the first login.

```
function (user, context, callback) {
    var count = context.stats && context.stats.loginsCount ? context.stats.loginsCount : 0;
    if (count > 1) {
        return callback(null, user, context);
    }

    //update metadata 
    // https://auth0.com/docs/rules/guides/metadata#update-user_metadata


    callback(null, user, context);
}
```